# Different sequence of syntax results in error

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to know whether there is something wrong with my coding if I try to reverse the order of my coding.

Suppose that I have a data which I name "data" to my system.
I try to retrieve the data using:

```
data[data.country=="country_2"].groupby("source").count()
```

which results in the result I want.

However if I try to reverse the order to be:

```
data.groupby("source")[data.country=="country_2"].count()
```

It returns to an error:

> KeyError: 'Columns not found: False, True'

I am newbie to Python and would like to know why such things happen for future references

Comment: There's no reason to *expect* things to work the same if you do things in a different order. Even in ordinary life, "unwrap sandwich" and then "eat it" produces a very different result from "eat sandwich" and then "unwrap it". The order you do things in matters.

Comment: The second way doesn't make any sense. `data.country == "country_2"` returns a series whose indexes correspond to indexes in the original dataframe. Those indexes don't exist in the grouped dataframe.

Comment: This error is specific to pandas/numpy.  You might get better answers if you add those tags to this question.

Comment: "I just want to know whether there is something wrong with my coding if I try to reverse the order of my coding." well, **you got a wrong result** when you tried this, so you already know there is something wrong. yes? "would like to know why such things" - you first: **why do you expect that it shouldn't matter** what the order is? If you try to spread peanut butter on bread *before* taking it out of the bag, you'll make a mess, right?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this lies in understanding what `data.country=="country_2"` is, and what square brackets do to different objects.

Since `data.country` is a column of a dataframe, it's a pandas series. If you print it out by itself, it will look something like this:

```
>>> print(data.country)
0    country_1
1    country_2
2    country_2
3    country_1
4    country_3
5    country_2
Name: country, dtype: object
```

Now with `data.country=="country_2"`, we're asking python to tell us if it's equal to the string "country_2". But since it's a series, instead of just saying False, it's going to give us a series full of true and false values that indicate which elements are equal:

```
>>> print(data.country=="country_2")
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: country, dtype: bool
```

Now when we slice a dataframe with a boolean series like this, it's going to give us a dataframe with just the rows that match up with the `True`s:

```
>>> print(data[data.country=="country_2"])
     country    city source
1  country_2  city_2  email
2  country_2  city_3  email
5  country_2  city_6   text
```

So with your first line that worked, you're really doing two things. You're filtering your dataframe for just the rows that have country_2 in the country column, and then you're doing the groupby/count.

When you slice a dataframe with square brackets, it does something different depending on what you put inside the square brackets:

- Boolean series, like the above example: filter the rows
- String, e.x. `data['country']`: this extracts a single column. `data['country']` is equivalent to `data.country`
- List of strings, e.x. `data[['country', 'city']]`: this gives us a dataframe with just the columns listed.

When we write `data.groupby("source")`, that doesn't give us a dataframe. The object it gives us is technically a DataFrameGroupBy object, which is basically a container for a bunch of smaller dataframes - one for each group. When we add the `.count()` at the end, we're telling python to apply the count function to each group, which counts up the number of entries in each column:

```
>>> print(data.groupby('source').count())
        country  city
source               
email         3     3
text          3     3
```

We can slice the DataFrameGroupBy Object with square brackets, but it doesn't behave exactly the same as slicing an actual dataframe that way. If we give it a column name or a list of column names, it tells the groupby to only apply the function to those columns:

```
>>> print(data.groupby('source')['country'].count())
source
email    3
text     3
Name: country, dtype: int64
```

This is a pretty normal thing to do with `.count()`, since it's going to be the same for every column, so there's no need to apply it to more than one. But you tried in your second line to give it a boolean series. Since it's a DataFrameGroupBy object and not an actual dataframe, it doesn't do anything special like filtering with that series - it treats it like a list. That is, it tries to select the columns with names that match the values in the list. That's why you got the error it did - it tried to select just the columns named `True` and `False`, but they don't exist.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't expect things to just work, or to work the same way, if you permute the order like this. But digging into *why* this doesn't work can be educational in understanding what your code is actually doing.